# Taylor series in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I am working on finding the Taylor series of 
$$\frac1{az+b}$$ in powers of $z.$ 
How to start with it 
Any help in details...

Comment: it will be nice to start with some specific values for $a$ and $b.$ it is hard to do math in the most general setting. go from a specific to general in small steps.

Comment: Hint: modify the formula for the geometric series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its helpful first to know the formula for the geometric series,

$$ \frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n \qquad (\vert z \vert < 1 ), $$

then we can modify your series to look like a geometric series,

$$ \frac{1}{az+b} = \frac{1}{b} \frac{1}{ az/b +1} = \frac{1}{b}\frac{1}{1- (-az/b)} = \frac{1}{b} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (az/b)^n \qquad (\vert z\vert < b/a).$$